# Image does not display on Pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am using Pyqt5, python3.9, and windows 11. I am trying to add an image to my app but it wont display anything as show below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(531, 316)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 491, 241))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/newPrefix/download.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())][1]
```

**My Application**:

[image: My Application]

This is my qrc file:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="newPrefix">
    <file>download.png</file>
    <file>background.gif</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And both the image and the main.py are in the same directory. Any idea why this does not work?

EDIT: The code seems to work on windows 10 but not on windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

you should first use `pyrcc5` and convert your `qrc` to `.py` :

for example, I do this :

```
pyrcc5 resourse.qrc -o logo_rc.py
```

then you should import it :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import logo_rc

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(550, 600)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 550, 600))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/images/photos.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**this is my out put :**

[image]